# How to write 8 bit data by macro in C?

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32

I write TFT LCD driver for stm32 and I need write 8 bit data to LCD. I found this macro in mcufriend's library, but I'm not sure how it works and how can I edit it. Can somebody write how to write macro like this and how it works ?

Macro from mcufriend's library:

```
#define write_8(d) { \
GPIOA->regs->BSRR = 0x0700 << 16; \
GPIOB->regs->BSRR = 0x0438 << 16; \
GPIOC->regs->BSRR = 0x0080 << 16; \
GPIOA->regs->BSRR = (((d) & (1<<0)) << 9) \
           | (((d) & (1<<2)) << 8) \
           | (((d) & (1<<7)) << 1); \
GPIOB->regs->BSRR = (((d) & (1<<3)) << 0) \
           | (((d) & (1<<4)) << 1) \
           | (((d) & (1<<5)) >> 1) \
           | (((d) & (1<<6)) << 4); \
GPIOC->regs->BSRR = (((d) & (1<<1)) << 6); \
}
```

Comment: So it is writing a bunch of magical values to a hardware register. What are these values? The datasheet will tell you.

Comment: We are not the support site of wherever you got this macro from. Not sure qheat you intend to do; if you want to write an octet to a GPIO on the STM32, you can easily use a simple byte-write to ODR. If that is for some bit-banding protocol, use a function. Never use a macro where a function will do! It is bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like STM32duino syntax:

*PORT*->regs->*REGISTER* = *value*

with *REGISTER* being BSRR, the bit set reset register. The value you assign to this sets pins 0-15 of *PORT* high, if the corresponding bit is set. Bits 16-31 act the same as bits 0-15 of the BRR register; if the bit is set, the corresponding pin is set low. If a bit is zero, the state of the corresponding pin is unchanged.

Lets look at each individual assignment in the macro.

---

```
GPIOA->regs->BSRR = 0x0700 << 16;
```

This sets pins GPIOA8, GPIOA9, and GPIOA10 low. (`(1<<8) | (1<<9) | (1<<10) == 0x0700`, and high 16 bits of BSRR sets the corresponding bits low.)

---

```
GPIOB->regs->BSRR = 0x0438 << 16;
```

This sets pins GPIOB3, GPIOB4, GPIOB5, and GPIOB10 low.

---

```
GPIOC->regs->BSRR = 0x0080 << 16;
```

This sets pin GPIOC7 low.

---

```
GPIOA->regs->BSRR = 
         (((d) & (1<<0)) << 9)
       | (((d) & (1<<2)) << 8)
       | (((d) & (1<<7)) << 1);
```

If bit 0 of `d` is set, then pin GPIOA9 is set high.

If bit 2 of `d` is set, then pin GPIOA10 is set high.

If bit 7 of `d` is set, then pin GPIOA8 is set high.

---

```
GPIOB->regs->BSRR = 
         (((d) & (1<<3)) << 0)
       | (((d) & (1<<4)) << 1)
       | (((d) & (1<<5)) >> 1)
       | (((d) & (1<<6)) << 4);
```

If bit 3 of `d` is set, pin GPIOB3 is set high.

If bit 4 of `d` is set, pin GPIOB5 is set high.

If bit 5 of `d` is set, pin GPIOB4 is set high.

If bit 6 of `d` is set, pin GPIOB10 is set high.

---

```
GPIOC->regs->BSRR =
         (((d) & (1<<1)) << 6);
```

If bit 1 of `d` is set, pin GPIOC7 is set high.

---

The first three lines set pins GPIOA8, GPIOA9, GPIOA10, GPIOB3, GPIOB4, GPIOB5, GPIOB10, and GPIOC7 low.

The rest of the lines set pins GPIOA9, GPIOC7, GPIOA10, GPIOB3, GPIOB5, GPIOB4, GPIOB10, and GPIOA8 high, if the corresponding bit in `d` is set.

In other words, the macro sets the pins A9,C7,A10,B3,B5,B4,B10,A8 high if the corresponding bit 0-7 in `d` is set, and low if clear.

I would hazard a guess that the macro is used to communicate with a peripheral (likely a display) using 8-bit parallel bus, with pin A9 corresponding to the least significant bit of each parallel byte sent, and pin A8 to the most significant bits; the other pins as listed above in between.